# Como armar Array asociativo para enviar datos

Tags: php, array

Necesito recorrer arreglos que tienen información que debo enviar a un web service, para eso estoy haciendo uso de array asociativos y array_push().

Tengo el siguiente codigo pero la información no la estoy enviando de forma correcta:

```
    $data = array(
    'argWSAutenticacionEmpresa' => array(
        'Token' => $ta->token,
        'Sign'     => $ta->sign,
        'CuitEmpresaConectada'     => $afip->CUIT,
        'TipoAgente' => 'TRSP',
        'Rol' => 'TRSP'
    ),
    'argRegistrarTitulosCBC' => array(
        'IdTransaccion' => $idProceso->idProceso,
        'InformacionTitulosDoc' => array(
            'IdentificadorViaje' => $viaje->idViaje,
        )
    )
);

foreach ($titulos as $titulo) {

    array_push(
        $data,
        array(
            'Titulos' => array(
                'Titulo' => array(
                    'FechaEmbarque' => $titulo['fecha_embarque'],
                    'CodigoPuertoEmbarque' => $titulo['id_puerto_embarque'],
                    'FechaCargaLugarOrigen' => $titulo['fecha_carga'],
                    'LugarOrigen' => $titulo['lugar_origen'],
                    'CodigoPaisLugarOrigen' => $titulo['id_pais_origen'],
                    'NumeroConocimiento' => $titulo['nro_conocimiento'],
                    'CodigoPuertoTrasbordo' => $titulo['id_puerto_transbordo'],
                    'CodigoPuertoDescarga' => $titulo['id_puerto_descarga'],
                    'FechaDescarga' => $titulo['fecha_descarga'],
                    'CodigoPaisDestino' => $titulo['id_pais_destino'],
                    'MarcaBultos' => $titulo['marca_bultos'],
                    'Consignatario' => $titulo['consignatario'],
                    'NotificarA' => $titulo['notificar_a'],
                    'IndicadorConsolidado' => $titulo['consolidado'],
                    'IndicadorTransitoTrasbordo' => $titulo['idTransTransb'],
                    'TipoDocumentoDestinatarioMercaderia' => $titulo['id_tipo_doc_des'],
                    'IdentificadorDestinatarioMercaderia' => $titulo['idDestinatario'],
                    'CodigoPaisEmisionPasaporteDestinatario' => $titulo['id_pais_pasaporte'],
                    'PosicionArancelaria' => $titulo['posicion_arancelaria'],
                    'IndicadorOperadorLogisticoSeguro' => $titulo['operador_logistico'],
                    'IndicadorTransitoMonitoreado' => $titulo['transito_monitoreado'],
                    'IndicadorRenar' => $titulo['renar'],
                    'RazonSocialFowarderExterior' => $titulo['razon_socual_forwarder'],
                    'IndicadorTributarioForwarderExterior' => $titulo['idForwarder'],
                    'CodigoPaisEmisorIdentificadorForwarderExterior' => $titulo['id_pais_forwarder'],
                    'Comentario' => $titulo['comentario'],
                    'CodigoLugarOperativoDescarga' => $titulo['id_lugar_operativo'],
                    'CodigoAduanaDescarga' => $titulo['id_aduana']
                )
            )
        )
    );

    foreach ($arrayLineasMercaderia as $lineaMercaderia) {
        if ($lineaMercaderia['nro_conocimiento'] == $titulo['nro_conocimiento']) {
            array_push(
                $data,
                array(
                    'Mercaderias' => array(
                        'LineaMercaderia' => array(
                            'NumeroLinea' => $lineaMercaderia['nro_linea'],
                            'CodigoEmbalaje' => $lineaMercaderia['id_embalaje'],
                            'TipoEmbalaje' => $lineaMercaderia['id_tipo_embalaje'],
                            'CondicionContenedor' => $lineaMercaderia['condicion_contenedor'],
                            'CantidadManifestada' => $lineaMercaderia['cant_manifestada'],
                            'PesoVolumenManifestado' => $lineaMercaderia['peso_volumen_mani'],
                            'DescripcionMercaderia' => $lineaMercaderia['descripcion'],
                            'NumeroBultos' => $lineaMercaderia['nro_bultos'],
                            'TipoCarga' => $lineaMercaderia['tipo_carga'],
                            'Comentario' => $lineaMercaderia['comentario']
                        )
                    )

                )
            );
        }
    }

    foreach ($arrayContenedor as $contenedor) {
            array_push(
                $data,
                array(
                    'Contenedores' => array(
                        'Contenedor' => array(
                            'CuitAtaOperadorContenedor' => $contenedor['cuit_operador'],
                            'CaracteristicasContenedor' => $contenedor['caracteristicas'],
                            'Tara' => $contenedor['tara'],
                            'PesoBruto' => $contenedor['peso_bruto'],
                            'NumeroPrecintoOrigen' => $contenedor['nro_precinto_orig'],
                            'FechaVencimientoContenedor' => $contenedor['fecha_vto'],
                            'CodigoPuertoEmbarque' => $contenedor['id_puerto_embarque'],
                            'FechaEmbarque' => $contenedor['fecha_embarque']
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Al hacer un var_dump($data), puedo ver que lo estoy enviando de la siguiente forma:

```
'argRegistrarTitulosCBC' => array(
    'IdTransaccion' => $idProceso->idProceso,
    'InformacionTitulosDoc' => array(
        'IdentificadorViaje' => $viaje->idViaje,
    ),
)
'0' => array(
    'Titulos' => array(
        'Titulo' => array(
            ...
        )    
    )
)
```

Y necesito enviarlo asi para que el web service tome la información:

```
'argRegistrarTitulosCBC' => array(
    'IdTransaccion' => $idProceso->idProceso,
    'InformacionTitulosDoc' => array(
        'IdentificadorViaje' => $viaje->idViaje,
    ),
    'Titulos' => array(
        array(
            array(
                'Titulo' => array(
                    ...
                )    
            )    
        )
    )
)
```

¿Como puedo hacer para enviar la información del $data en forma correcta?
No se como lograr el formato que me pide.
Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo quieres agregarlo dentro de este objeto `[argRegistrarTitulosCBC]` para eso en vez de push puedes solo crear un nuevo objeto, por ejemplo:

```
$data['argRegistrarTitulosCBC']['Titulos'] = array(
            'Titulo' => array(
                'FechaEmbarque' => $titulo['fecha_embarque'],
                'CodigoPuertoEmbarque' => $titulo['id_puerto_embarque'],
                'FechaCargaLugarOrigen' => $titulo['fecha_carga'],
                'LugarOrigen' => $titulo['lugar_origen'],
                'CodigoPaisLugarOrigen' => $titulo['id_pais_origen'],
                'NumeroConocimiento' => $titulo['nro_conocimiento'],
                'CodigoPuertoTrasbordo' => $titulo['id_puerto_transbordo'],
                'CodigoPuertoDescarga' => $titulo['id_puerto_descarga'],
                'FechaDescarga' => $titulo['fecha_descarga'],
                'CodigoPaisDestino' => $titulo['id_pais_destino'],
                'MarcaBultos' => $titulo['marca_bultos'],
                'Consignatario' => $titulo['consignatario'],
                'NotificarA' => $titulo['notificar_a'],
                'IndicadorConsolidado' => $titulo['consolidado'],
                'IndicadorTransitoTrasbordo' => $titulo['idTransTransb'],
                'TipoDocumentoDestinatarioMercaderia' => $titulo['id_tipo_doc_des'],
                'IdentificadorDestinatarioMercaderia' => $titulo['idDestinatario'],
                'CodigoPaisEmisionPasaporteDestinatario' => $titulo['id_pais_pasaporte'],
                'PosicionArancelaria' => $titulo['posicion_arancelaria'],
                'IndicadorOperadorLogisticoSeguro' => $titulo['operador_logistico'],
                'IndicadorTransitoMonitoreado' => $titulo['transito_monitoreado'],
                'IndicadorRenar' => $titulo['renar'],
                'RazonSocialFowarderExterior' => $titulo['razon_socual_forwarder'],
                'IndicadorTributarioForwarderExterior' => $titulo['idForwarder'],
                'CodigoPaisEmisorIdentificadorForwarderExterior' => $titulo['id_pais_forwarder'],
                'Comentario' => $titulo['comentario'],
                'CodigoLugarOperativoDescarga' => $titulo['id_lugar_operativo'],
                'CodigoAduanaDescarga' => $titulo['id_aduana']
            )
        );
```

Esto entra a $data, busca el objeto `argRegistrarTitulosCBC` y dentro crea un nuevo objeto al que le agrega los datos que le asignes.

Basicamente debes de seguir la misma estructura para los demas datos.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta
Intente seguir tu consejo y cambie el cofigo por lo siguiente:

$data['argRegistrarTitulosCBC']['InformacionTitulosDoc']['Titulos'] = array(
        'Titulo' => array(......
foreach ($arrayLineasMercaderia as $lineaMercaderia) {
        if ($lineaMercaderia['nro_conocimiento'] == $titulo['nro_conocimiento']) {

            $data['argRegistrarTitulosCBC']['InformacionTitulosDoc']['Titulos']['Titulo'] =
                array(....
Pero me da el error: "SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'FechaEmbarque' property"

Comment: Pues segun tu error le hace falta el parametro FechaEmbarque, antes de enviar la peticion haz un var_dump del array para ver que estructura regresa, si la estructura es correcta talvez la variable esta vacio o puede que el objeto deba ir en un orden diferente, eso ya depende de que datos vas a enviar y en que orden se debe enviar.

Comment: Ya pude acomodarlo, el problema es que haciendolo de esa forma si tengo mas de un titulo solo queda grabado el ultimo, deberia guardar todos:

foreach ($titulos as $titulo) {


$data['argRegistrarTitulosCBC']['InformacionTitulosDoc']['Titulos'] = array(
        'Titulo' => array(
            'FechaEmbarque' => $titulo['fecha_embarque'],
            'CodigoPuertoEmbarque' => $titulo['id_puerto_embarque'],
            'FechaCargaLugarOrigen' => $titulo['fecha_carga'],
...
            'Mercaderias' => array(),
            'Contenedores' => array()
        )
    );
}

Comment: perdon, te cito porque no se si llegan los comentarios @JefferzonBol

Comment: Creo que pasa porque estas agregando dentro de este item ["Titulos"] cuando creas otro item como ya existe solo se sobreescribe, lo que creo que debes hacer es tener algo como esto $titulos_array = array(); y hacer array push a $titulos_array para que se llene de items, solo asi podras tener mas de un item sin que se sobre escriba, al final llenas el $data con esos titulos $data['argRegistrarTitulosCBC']['InformacionTitulosDoc'] = $titulos_array; es decir, no debes de usar el objeto [Titulos] porque siempre se va a sobreescribir al ser un key repetido.